# como mostrar el nombre y valor de un string y como eliminar uno

Tags: c, string, funciones, estructuras-de-datos, codeblocks

Necesito poner el valor máximo y mínimo de los datos de 3 paises que cargo.
¿Como podría hacer que me aparezca: `"valor máximo en Argentina con 43"`?.
Pero solo me aparece el numero máximo y no el nombre, en otra opción tengo que eliminar un pais de los que cargue y necesito una ayuda con eso, estoy usando funciones, estructuras y strings
¡MUCHAS GRACIAS!.

```c
void carga(int c, struct carga info[c]) //ESTOS SON LOS DATOS QUE CARGO
{


    for(int i=0; i<c; i++)
    {

        printf("\nIngresar pais :\t");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(info[i].paises);

        printf("\nIngrese la poblacion :\t");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%i",&info[i].poblacion);

        printf("\nIngrese el continente :\t");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(info[i].continente);

        printf("\nIngrese la superficie :\t");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%lf",&info[i].superficie);

        system("cls");

    }
}
```

Comment: Si quieres llenar el array dentro de la funcion usa punteros: `struct carga* info` y no te engañes con `struct carga info[c]` pues el compilador al final lo convertirá en puntero, tambien a eso se le conoce VLA(Variant Lenght Array (Array de longitud variante) ) y no es muy recomendado usarlo: `void name_func(int i){int VLA[i];/*Nota que VLA es cuando declaras el tamaño del array usando una varianle*/}` Lo que hace el compilador en realidad hace es recervar `i*tipo_dato` de la pila y puede ocacionar un `Stack Overflow(Devordamiento de pila) ES(Español, coloco ES porque así se llama este sitio`

Comment: Si usaste malloc, puedes crear otro array con malloc(`struct carga* array=(struct carga*)malloc(sizeof(struct carga)*len_array_anterior));` y agregarle todos los elementos excepto el que deseas eliminar y despues liberas el array anterior(`free`} y retorna el nuevo array `return array;`, si te guias por el nombre del pais que quieres eliminar puedes usar `strcmp(char*,char*);` se incluye en `<string.h>` para saber si son iguales.

Comment: Nota: Para hacer eso creo(No estoy muy seguro) tienes que copiar *todos* los elementos de la estructura anterior a la estructura nueva. Y si tienes algun problema ya sea en copilacion o ejecucion actualiza esta pregunta.